# How to get value at the current linear address in the IDC script?

Tags: ida

I'm trying to extract a float value at the current linear address in the IDC script, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Disassembly example:

```
.rdata:004F8360 flt_4F8360      dd 0.69999999           ; DATA XREF: sub_4071E0+68r
```

I want to print this float value in the console message like this:

```
Value: 0.69999999
```

I've tried (unsuccessfully):

- `Dword(ea)`

  ```
  Message("Value: %f", Dword(ea));

  Value: 1.060320051e9
  ```
- `GetManyBytes(ea, 4, 0)`:

  ```
  Message("Value: %f", GetManyBytes(ea, 4, 0));

  Value: 3.33e2
  ```

So how does one achieves this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By looking at the [documentation](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html).

Use [`GetFloat`](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc.html#idc.GetFloat).

Comment: Thanks! The reason I asked, is that I couldn't find it in the docs. Now I see, that it's because I've looked at the [wrong ones](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/162.shtml).